# jdbc.OracleDriver error while building Jenkins job

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jenkins, continuous-integration

I would be very thankful, if somebody could explain this to me. What the hell this Jenkins is trying to do in my situation.

Here is the piece of my log file: 
[image]

I have created the simple job. Have linked to it my SVN repository, have set Maven Goals, same things as always. But this time he refused to work. The last 3 lines are repeating every minute. I have waited for an hour and then aborted the job. 
In my `MAVEN_OPTS` I said to him where he can find JDBC Driver.

[image]

I have a couple of another jobs with the same configuration, and they are working pretty fine.
Is Jenkins trying to download the jdbc Driver for each testcase? Or am I wrong?
How can I fix this?

Thanks for the help.

***P.S.*** here is the log file, at the end I have aborted job manually.

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/jobs/SCM/jobs/DInvoice/jobs/InvoiceUserInterface/workspace
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at /var/jenkins_home/jobs/SCM/jobs/DInvoice/jobs/InvoiceUserInterface/workspace
Cleaning local Directory .
Checking out http://development.bonprix.net/svn/Java/app/Invoice/InvoiceUserInterface/trunk/InvoiceUserInterface at revision '2016-07-28T13:44:48.317 +0000'
A         src
A         src/test
A         src/test/resources
A         src/test/resources/testng-suite.xml
A         src/test/resources/application-test.properties
A         src/test/java
A         src/test/java/de
A         src/test/java/de/bonprix
A         src/test/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice
A         src/test/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules
A         src/test/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules/invoice
A         src/test/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules/invoice/InvoicePresenterTest.java
A         src/main
A         src/main/java
A         src/main/java/de
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/DInvoiceUI.java
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/model
AU        src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/model/DiscountsClaims.java
AU        src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/model/AuShipmentType.java
AU        src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/model/GnCurrency.java
AU        src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/model/IvType.java
AU        src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/model/InvoicePosition.java
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/dao
AU        src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/dao/InvoiceDao.java
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules/invoice
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules/invoice/ui
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules/invoice/ui/InvoiceViewImpl.java
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules/invoice/InvoiceModule.java
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules/invoice/InvoicePresenter.java
A         src/main/java/de/bonprix/dinvoice/modules/invoice/InvoiceView.java
A         src/main/resources
A         src/main/resources/de
A         src/main/resources/de/bonprix
A         src/main/resources/de/bonprix/dinvoice
A         src/main/resources/de/bonprix/dinvoice/dao
AU        src/main/resources/de/bonprix/dinvoice/dao/InvoiceDao.xml
A         src/main/resources/de/bonprix/dinvoice/dinvoice.css
A         src/main/resources/application.properties
A         src/main/resources/i18n
A         src/main/resources/i18n/dinvoice-messages.properties
A         src/main/resources/i18n/dinvoice-messages_en.properties
A         src/main/resources/i18n/dinvoice-messages_de.properties
A         src/main/webapp
A         pom.xml
At revision 21398

Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 38864
[workspace] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Doracle.driver.path=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/ojdbc6.jar -cp /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.7.jar:/opt/maven/maven-current/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/opt/maven/maven-current/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /opt/maven/maven-current /var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.60.jar /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.7.jar /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar 38864
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/jenkins_home/jobs/SCM/jobs/DInvoice/jobs/InvoiceUserInterface/workspace/pom.xml -s /opt/maven/maven-current/conf/settings.xml -gs /opt/maven/maven-current/conf/settings.xml clean deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for de.bonprix.invoice:InvoiceUserInterface:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin is missing. @ de.bonprix.base.webbase:WebBase:4.4.26, /opt/maven/cache/de/bonprix/base/webbase/WebBase/4.4.26/WebBase-4.4.26.pom, line 624, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin is missing. @ de.bonprix.base.webbase:WebBase:4.4.26, /opt/maven/cache/de/bonprix/base/webbase/WebBase/4.4.26/WebBase-4.4.26.pom, line 637, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ de.bonprix.base.webbase:WebBase:4.4.26, /opt/maven/cache/de/bonprix/base/webbase/WebBase/4.4.26/WebBase-4.4.26.pom, line 628, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin is missing. @ line 60, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 68, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin is missing. @ de.bonprix.base.webbase:WebBase:4.4.26, /opt/maven/cache/de/bonprix/base/webbase/WebBase/4.4.26/WebBase-4.4.26.pom, line 612, column 12
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.groupId' for org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ de.bonprix.base.webbase:WebBase:4.4.26, /opt/maven/cache/de/bonprix/base/webbase/WebBase/4.4.26/WebBase-4.4.26.pom, line 221, column 16
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ de.bonprix.base.webbase:WebBase:4.4.26, /opt/maven/cache/de/bonprix/base/webbase/WebBase/4.4.26/WebBase-4.4.26.pom, line 222, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building InvoiceUserInterface 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (727 B at 3.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (727 B at 3.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (605 B at 19.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (605 B at 17.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/mojo/properties-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/codehaus/mojo/properties-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/codehaus/mojo/properties-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (421 B at 14.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/mojo/properties-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (421 B at 13.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/codehaus/mojo/buildnumber-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/mojo/buildnumber-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/mojo/buildnumber-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (602 B at 21.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/codehaus/mojo/buildnumber-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (602 B at 21.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (743 B at 29.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://digistyle.bonprix.net/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (743 B at 27.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ InvoiceUserInterface ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.12:add-source (add-source) @ InvoiceUserInterface ---
[INFO] Source directory: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/SCM/jobs/DInvoice/jobs/InvoiceUserInterface/workspace/target/generated-sources/apt added.
[INFO] Source directory: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/SCM/jobs/DInvoice/jobs/InvoiceUserInterface/workspace/target/generated-sources/classes added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) @ InvoiceUserInterface ---
[WARNING] No processors specified. Using default discovery mechanism.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ InvoiceUserInterface ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ InvoiceUserInterface ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to /var/jenkins_home/jobs/SCM/jobs/DInvoice/jobs/InvoiceUserInterface/workspace/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ InvoiceUserInterface ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ InvoiceUserInterface ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/jenkins_home/jobs/SCM/jobs/DInvoice/jobs/InvoiceUserInterface/workspace/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ InvoiceUserInterface ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/SCM/jobs/DInvoice/jobs/InvoiceUserInterface/workspace/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running de.bonprix.dinvoice.modules.invoice.InvoicePresenterTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7a92922
Jul 28, 2016 1:44:56 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@6121c9d6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@87f383f, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@4eb7f003, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@eafc191, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@612fc6eb]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Jul 28, 2016 1:44:57 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@77a57272: startup date [Thu Jul 28 13:44:57 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 28, 2016 1:44:57 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'aspectConfiguration' of type [class de.bonprix.configuration.AspectConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48895d0c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Using test database connection test at jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.16.1.194)(PORT=18000)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)))
Jul 28, 2016 1:44:58 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
Build was aborted

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Aborted by admin
channel stopped
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] done
Finished: ABORTED
```

Comment: No, it just says it is connecting to the db, and loaded the oracle jdbc driver.

Comment: @OldProgrammer why is he doing this every minute?

Comment: It does that because unit tests are run in (relative) isolation, so it will repeatedly connect in your tests. Note that would have been better (more readable and searchable) to post the actual **text** of the log, not a screenshot.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel okey, you are right. I have posted the log file, but I am not sure that it would help much